# posted value is not displaying when use enctype as multipart/form-data in cakephp

Tags: php, forms, cakephp

I am working in cakephp.I have created one form that include file upload and textbox nad textarea.

Here, my html code looks like below :

```
<form action="" id="frmReg" method="post" enctype= "multipart/form-data">
   <div style="position:relative; margin-bottom:30px;" class="fildtpart4">
      <label><?php __d('statictext', 'Question', false); ?>:</label>
      <span>
          <textarea class="validate[required]" name="question1['question']" cols="" rows=""></textarea>
          <div style="color: red; position:absolute ; bottom:-25px ;" id="charNum"></div>
     </span>  
     <div class="clear"></div>
     <div class="fildtpart3">
        <label><?php __d('statictext', 'Currect Answer', false); ?></label>
        <span>
           <input name="question1['currect_ans']" type="text" class="validate[required]" id="" value="">
           <input type="file" class="validate[required]" onchange="showMyImage1(this)" name="question1['sponsor_image']" id="" />
           <input type="file" class="validate[required]" onchange="showMyImage2(this)" name="question1['question_image2']" id="" />
        </span>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
        <div class="clear10"></div>  
     </div>
   </div>
<form>
```

when I submit this form then it will shows only image not all data.

In my controller, I have written :

```
 function add_polls()
 { 
    print_r($this->params['form']);exit;
 }
```

Then it gives output like :

```
array(
    [question1]=>array(
                    [name] => Array
                              (
                                 ['sponsor_image'] => contact.jpg
                                 ['question_image2'] => contact.jpg
                              )
                    [type] => Array
                              (
                                 ['sponsor_image'] => image/jpeg
                                 ['question_image2'] => image/jpeg
                              )
                    [tmp_name] => Array
                                   (
                                     ['sponsor_image'] => /tmp/phpUK7Vcj
                                     ['question_image2'] => /tmp/php3SCWGZ
                                   )
                    [error] => Array
                               (
                                 ['sponsor_image'] => 0
                                 ['question_image2'] => 0
                               )
                    [size] => Array
                              (
                                ['sponsor_image'] => 2305
                                ['question_image2'] => 2305
                              )
                      )
         )
```

Here, its not printed **question1['currect_ans']** and **question1['question']**.When I remove enctype from the form then it will shows all value. So how can I resolve this problem?

**Note:** CakePHP vesrion is 1.3.13.

Comment: Can you please try setting enctype to multipart/mixed.

Comment: @DiomedesAndreou can I upload image if I use enctype as multipart/mixed ?

Comment: Please always mention the exact CakePHP version that you are using!

Comment: @ndm CakePHP version is **CakePHP(tm) v 0.2.9**

Comment: There is no such CakePHP version (anymore), you're looking at a `@since` tag most probably. The proper version number can be found in the `VERSION.txt` file in the CakePHP core code folder. Also please add such info to your question, and tag it accordingly, don't just put it in a comment.

Comment: What you are using ajax ? You can test print_r($_POST); exit; instead $this->params['form']

Comment: @user5200704 No,its not working.

Comment: @user5200704 I have change as you said but i can not get data.I got only image data.

Comment: Input name is wrong formatted ['question'] replace with [question]
or change different name question1 to another but only change in input file bcz file value store in php global $_FILES array and other inputs value store in  global  $_POST array variable in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

This is a mixture of how PHP handles files, and you not following the CakePHP conventions, causing CakePHP to "overwrite" your other form data.

You should use the form helper, that way you would avoid the problem in the first place, unless of course you'd fiddle with the field names and use such clashing ones again.

Adding everything in `question1`, including files, will result in the files being grouped under `question1` in `$_FILES`, just as shown in your question, ie

```
Array(
    [question1] => Array(
        [name] => Array(
            ['sponsor_image'] => contact.jpg
            ['question_image2'] => contact.jpg
        )
        // ...
    )
)
```

and the rest of the form data in `$_POST` using the same key, ie

```
Array(
    [question1] => Array(
        ['question'] => 'foo',
        ['currect_ans'] => 'bar'
    )
)
```

You should already smell the upcoming clash.

CakePHP will first fill `$params['form']` with `$_POST`, and then iterate over `$_FILES` and use the keys to set the file data in `$params['form']` too, which will lead to the previously set form data, ie the text inputs, to be overwritten, as both use the key, `question1`.

- **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/1.3.13/cake/dispatcher.php#L248**
- **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/1.3.13/cake/dispatcher.php#L289-L293**

### tl;dr Follow the naming conventions, or use the form helper

Follow the CakePHP conventions and use the `data` key (and optionally a model name, which doesn't need to exist) to group the input, that way all data will be properly handled separately and made available via `Controller::$data`

```
name="data[question]"
name="data[currect_ans]"
name="data[sponsor_image]"
name="data[question_image2]"
```

No need to use quotes for nested keys btw.

Even better, as already mentioned, use the form helper, it will automatically create proper fieldnames.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Core Helpers > Form > Field naming convention](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Helpers/Form.html#field-naming-convention)**
- **[Cookbook > Core Helpers > Form > File Fields](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Helpers/Form.html#file-fields)**

Answer (score -1):

So i reproduced your issue and i'm reporting the following.

On my cakephp 3.x your form works great by submitting with 'regular' HTTP post. (I added an `<input type="submit">` to your form).

```
[
    'question1' => [
        'question' => 'da',
        'currect_ans' => 'da',
        'sponsor_image' => [
            'name' => 'Mobile version.png',
            'type' => 'image/png',
            'tmp_name' => '/tmp/php3A021O',
            'error' => (int) 0,
            'size' => (int) 149447
        ],
        'question_image2' => [
            'name' => 'Mobile version.png',
            'type' => 'image/png',
            'tmp_name' => '/tmp/phpi6VWxl',
            'error' => (int) 0,
            'size' => (int) 149447
        ]
    ]
]
```

So how are you submitting your data? Is it through ajax? What version of cakephp are you using? Try answering these questions so i can help you further on.

Comment: No I have used simple post method to send my data. And I am using CakePHP 1.3.13 version of cakephp.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried getting the data using

```
$postedData = $this->request->data;
```